# firebase is charging me even though I am not exceeded the usage limit

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am using the firebase blaze plan for using cloud functions.
I never exceeded the usage limit. But It is still charging me. And every day it stacking. My app is not published. So, Only I am using for debugging.

Here is the images:

The payment charging:
[image]

Cloud Function using:
[image]

Mountly Active User's number:
[image]

I should never be paid to firebase. But It is always charging up every day. Even there are no active cloud functions or any usage record. What happened? And How can I fix it?

Comment: Why aren't you on the free Spark plan? The Blaze plan charges you for bandwidth and storage.

Comment: I need to use cloud functions for my project.

Comment: Then you're paying for bandwidth and storage, I'd presume.

Comment: There is not too many value in my storage .it has only 1 MB data. Also , i do know mean of bandwith. What is it ? And How can i check it ?

Comment: Stack Overflow won't be able to address billing concerns. You can check this documentation on [Firebase pricing](https://firebase.google.com/pricing) since you enabled Cloud Functions, this would be charged accordingly. You may contact Firebase support through this [link](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/firestore/billing/help).